# Codeigniter - Twitter. oauth callback wrong redirection

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter

I’m working with Elliot Haughin’s Twitter library. After twitter login I get this callback redirection http://social.mydomain.com/?/invite/twitter/auth . 
Do you know why the “?” is inserted before the uri?

I have set PATH_INFO and allowed query strings. My htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|resources)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query strings should be disabled in order for this to work.

Comment: I think I messed up before while trying to get facebook to work. Now it is working on both, twitter and facebook. Thanks! +1